# How many times a number is divided into another number in Java

Tags: java

I want to know how many times one number fits inside another number. Example:

24 / 2 = 12

12 / 2 = 6    //it fits in 6 times...

6 / 2 = 3    //it fits in 3 times ...

What I've done

```
while (done == false) {                    
    if(start == 0) {
          resultDivide = a[0] / a[1];
          start = 1;
          counter ++;
    } else {
          tempresult = resultDivide / a[1];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Where do you change the `done` flag inside the loop ?

Comment: What help do you need ? This is not the complete code either !

Comment: Off topic . .`while(!done)` looks better than `while(done == false)`..

Comment: To be honest, logarithm is the way to do it. http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/logarithms.html

Comment: What's the *question* here? Unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Let `a` is 24 and `b` is 3 in your example

```
if(a == 0){
//ans is infinity
}
else {
    int copy = a;
    int times = 0;
    while(copy % b == 0){
        copy /= b;
        ++times;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that will do it:

```
public static int numDiv(int a, int b) {
    if (b < 2) // nonsense value
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int result = 0;
    for (; a % b == 0; a /= b)
        result++;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((num1 % num2 == 0) && num2 != 0)
{
    num1 /= num2;
    times++;
}
```